# Complete the Proof. Let $A$ be a countable set, and let $A^n$ be the set of all $n$-tuples of $A$. Then, $A^n$ is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

The problem asks to complete the proof:

> Let $A$ be a countable set, and let $A^n$ be the set of all n-tuples of $A$. Then, $A^n$ is countable.

And here's the blank:

[image]

[image]

I don't know whether to put $A \rightarrow \{(\boldsymbol{b}, a_n) | a_n \in A \} $ here or not.

I am confused by the part that I circled: why is "$a$" in bold text here? I think it should be $a_n$ who should maps to $(\boldsymbol{b}, a_n)$. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Bold text is typically used to represent a vector or n-tuple. The $a$ should be bold. To understand the map you can see that the map $(1,2,3) \rightarrow ((1,2),3)$ are between slightly different tuples but essentially the same which is the bijection they're talking about.

Comment: I honestly cannot understand what they are trying to get you to do here. The $f$ of the second box does not appear to be used anywhere, so what is the point of defining it? And if $\mathbf b$ represents a (large) part of $\mathbf a$, then one _cannot_ say one fixes $\mathbf b$ and then pretend to define a function where $\mathbf a$ stands for an arbitrary value, since that will most likely conflict with the chosen and fixed $\mathbf b$.